# Testing Firefox Browsers

Tags: firefox, testing

With Firefox updating more quickly, how do I test my sites on version 3 through the current version? Can I have multiple versions installed? How do I set that up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either run the installer for each (putting them in separate directories) or extract the content of the zip file for your platform.

Running `firefox -ProfileManager` will allow you to create new profiles (one per firefox version).

You can then run `firefox -P <profile>` (or create a shortcut in windows (don't forget to edit the properties to add the command line option) or shell script for it).

NOTE: run `firefox -?` for help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have multiple versions but you should create a new .profile for each one so data doesn't overlap.